# Should discussion of distribution of audio/video be allowed?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/1041/need-something-to-generate-a-podcast-xml-automagically) got closed because it's off-topic, and I can see why, however, it got me thinking:

In this day of new, do-it-yourself methods of distribution (such as [SoundCloud](http://www.soundcloud.com) and distributors like [TuneCore](http://www.tunecore.com)), is it actually useful for those that work mainly in Audio/Video to know about and discuss these methods, and ways of taking advantage of them?

Comment: Is there a way I can move it, or do I need to re-post?

Answer (score 3):

### It Depends

These things fit with the scope of the site:

- How to convert Video/Audio to a distributable format.
- Which format is recommended for a particular situation.
- Recording methods/equipment/format recommended for a particular distribution format.

These things may fit with the scope of the site depending on how they are asked:

- Where to distribute
- How to distribute

These things do not fit with the scope of the site:

**(please feel free to edit this community wiki answer to make it more complete/accurate)**

Comment: I wonder if the line should be drawn at the _commercial_ side of distribution.  For example 'Where is a good place to distribute my work' is allowed; 'How can I make loads of money out of my work' would not be so great.

Comment: I concur with making the distinction between commercial distribution (audio to digital stores for retail) and distribution of audio for commercial usage (e.g., the merits of using BWF or FLAC for transmitting audio between studio and radio station). However, technical discussion around the merits of various formats as used by the incumbent major digital retailers would also be a perfectly legitimate topic -- as would be discussion of mastering for lossy formats, approaching the workflow as a producer, etc etc...!